# joomla template custom html rewrite a component output

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

I'm using ja elastica free template with sobipro (joomla 2.5).

Joomla template system let me customize a view of a specific template.

Example:

joomlasite/templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/article/default.php

This file rewrite/customize the com_content output of an article.

I'm interestend in sobipro component who doesn't had a "view".

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose its a missing `float: left`. But I'm definitively not interested in investigate your complete CSS.

Comment: i've already tried it.
Don't answer, comment or vote down a answer if you're not interested.

Comment: I downvoted your question because of the way you formulate it. Give details to your code and tell us until when you know what happens. The other way is not how SO works... (if you update your question I will remove my downvote of course)

Comment: @godesign i've updated it after a better research on the template system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your component doesn't have a view you can't override with your template its view.

Templates can only rewrite using html/com_YOUCOMPONENT/YOURVIEW/ in your template directory.